# Java Socket: Server won't read input until client server is closed -> Server can't response to client

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a basic client <-> server connection in Java. When trying to write to the server, the client sends the details correctly, and the server stalls on reading it until the client output stream is closed. Though, once the output stream is closed it apparently closes the socket, and due to that the server can't reply to the client. Here's the main snippet of code that handles this interaction.

Client:

```
private void sendCmd(String cmd) {
    String infoToSend = cmd;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        System.out.println("Trying to send: " + com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64.encode(infoToSend.getBytes()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64.encode(infoToSend.getBytes()));
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("Socket is flushed");


        System.out.println("Waiting for Data");
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Trying to get data");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is)
        );

        String line;
        while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Server:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Got Connection");
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        String response;
        System.out.println("Response:");
        String decode = "";
        while ((response = in.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                decode = new String(Base64.decode(response));
            } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Decoded: " + decode);
        out.writeBytes("We got your message!");
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("Fail"); e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Would anyone be able to guide me on how to fix this error. Sorry if it's super easy and I'm just unable to see it.

Comment: where you print the decode variable?

Comment: @Omore Just to console as I try to debug this

Answer (score 0):

Sending

```
socket.shutdownOutput();
```

solved the issue.

Comment: where did you pui this line of code? 
Is that just equal to close the socket?